# Browser URL issue because special character like "&"

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a website using PHP and connected with a MySQL database. I also have an admindashboard for control the users with some features in PHP script I have coded.

```
<a href="../loginUser2.php?userName=<?php echo $SQLRow["userid"];?>" target="_blank" class="a">Records</a>
```

This code make a login URL link like this when complete with username

```
mydomain.com/loginUser2.php?userName=abc&xyz
```

In mysql from table take username abc&xyz or any user. everything is fine just in web browser when I click link for any user then user is automatically login with help of PHP. But when in any user name use symbol or special character LIKE currently i have issue in "&" symbol. when I edit the URL with my self and in web browser when i type manually link with replace of & with %26 link work and user login successfully. i just want if any how user is registered in MySQL database with contain any special character symbol like & or etc so how can I fix web browser work automatically handle this type of symbols and characters.

I tried one stupid thing in phpMyAdmin edit username column and update username like this  abc%26xyz I thought when I will update then its works like &=%26 but I am fail.

Comment: Look at [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but *"when i click link for any user then user is automatically login with help of php"* suggests a serious security vulnerability unless the subsequent code verifies that the "admin user" is indeed authorized to login as the user... but in this application, passing the username seems like a poor design choice -- your users presumably have an integer ID primary key, and that would be the more sensible thing to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `urlencode()` to send special characters and `urldecode()` to get encoded value.

```
<a href="../loginUser2.php?userName=<?php echo urlencode($SQLRow["userid"]);?>" target="_blank" class="a">Records</a>

urldecode($_GET['userName']);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `urldecode()`, this will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you hitting url in browser,  browser does url encode. Which converting '&' to '%26'. So in your loginUser2.php just put 'urldecode()' , where you accepting your get parameter values. It will again decode your value from 'abc%26xyz' to 'abc&xyz' .

try this:

```
urldecode($_GET['userName']);
```

Comment: `$_GET['userName']` will be decoded automatically.  The issue is that it needs to be encoded properly in the first place.